# Microsoft SQL report builder: Multiple row 'duplicates' to one row per ID

Tags: sql, report

Microsoft SQL Server report Builder

I have a query which returns a variety of information from our Community Intelligence database which runs something like this:

```
SELECT
viewadhocorganisation.[org_id]
..../other fields
viewadhocorganisationmainactivities.[Main Activity]

FROM
viewadhocorganisation LEFT JOIN viewadhocorganisationmainactivities
ON viewadhocorganisation.[OrganisationID] = viewadhocorganisationmainactivities.[Organisation ID]

WHERE
viewadhocorganisation.[city name] = 'MyCity'
```

This returns each organisation with its respective fields on a new row with each of its main activities listed seperately in a new row (i.e duplicating)
hence SELECT DISTINCT does nothing in this instance as each row is not strictly a duplicate

ie return is :

```
ID   | Org Name   | other fields  | Main Activity
1    | Org 1      | other fields  | Activity 1
1    | Org 1      | other fields  | Activity 2
1    | Org 1      | other fields  | Activity 3
1    | Org 1      | other fields  | Activity 4
2    | Org 2      | other fields  | Activity 1
2    | Org 2      | other fields  | Activity 5
2    | Org 2      | other fields  | Activity 7
2    | Org 2      | other fields  | Activity 8
```

Main Activity is a text string populated from a seperate Lookup Table (maintained by a central sysadmin) I have tried various SUM, AGGREGATE, (also tried various JOIN, LOOKUP SET but I seem to be running into a lot of errors though I may be using it incorrectly) but have yet to find a solution to get the desired output where all main activities are in one row seperated by a comma :

Output required:

`Org_ID | Org Name  | other fields  | Main Activity
1       | Org 1     | other fields  | Activity 1, Activity 2, Activity 3 
2       | Org 2     | other fields  | Activity 1, Activity 5, Activity 7`

The intention is to get a dump of information to integrated into google maps API showing address of Org 1, org 2 etc showing their main activities which I have a procedure for already but am unable to collate the Main activity field into one row

Edit: I have no access to the back end and can only report from the views and tables created by our vendor

Answer (score 0):

you can use temporary tables to achieve this.
make your desired string of activities in one temporary from viewadhocorganisationmainactivities then join that temp table with your main table i.e viewadhocorganisation.

Comment: Hi can you explain that in a little more details, im a bit of a newbie to this. In general I am unable to create tables/views as I have been provided with a set of views from the vendor from which to report from. I have very limited access to the backend as I am not sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table with itself and use the stuff clause to get the strings in a comma separated format. [See this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9471f/5)